# Is it safe to use a damaged heating element for my Kenmore dryer?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I cracked the ceramic piece that connects the wires to the heating coil while replacing my heating element in my dryer.  It is working, but I am wondering if it is safe? Any comment?

Comment: Can you post photos of the damaged part?  Depending on what it is and where the crack is, it could range from no big deal to severe fire and electrocution hazard...but its hard to tell if we can't see it.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I did take photos before I put the dryer back together, but I don't see how to post them from here.  The crack in the ceramic goes right between the prongs, and it looks like there is ceramic touching all of the metal.  My biggest fear is that I tried to super-glue it together, then (don't laugh) I cinched it together with a twist tie. Now I am terrified I created a fire hazard.  I dried a load of clothes yesterday, and sat next to the dryer the whole time, and it worked with no problems (or burning smells). Could I maybe text you a photo? Thanks

Comment: upload the image to imgur.com and post a link.  Superglue and twist ties on or next to the heating element certainly could be a fire hazard.  There are special high temperature glues that need to be used on such parts.

Comment: I uploaded 5 photos. the first 3 show the part before I installed it, and the last 2 show it installed and after I ran 3 loads of laundry.  The twist-tie material is all outside of the heating element cover. The link is: http://imgur.com/a/WORZR     Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the pictures its a little clearer.

I would replace that part.  There are plenty of appliance repair stores online with model lookups and diagrams to help you find the right one.

That twist tie is going to melt, eventually.  At least the plastic coating on it.  At best, it will smell terrible.  At worst it could start a small fire.

The more concerning part is what happens if your superglue fails (from the heat).  The heating coilay end up touching a moving part and get ripped up.  Or the 240V wires may touch something they shouldn't.  If your dryer plug is properly grounded, it should trip the breaker.  If not, it could shock someone.

The proper part probably only costs $5-15.  So might as well do it right.

If I couldn't obtain the part for some reason, I would remove the ceramic block, remove the superglue with nail polish remover, and glue it back together with something designed to work on ceramic in hot environments. Most adhesives will say on the bottle what temperatures they are ok for.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Although that IS the new part, the heating element comes as one unit and the ceramic piece I broke while pounding it into the housing is RIVETED on. I will have to buy an entire new unit  ($65.) or figure out how to get the ceramic piece off the old element I just took out and onto the new unit.  Oh well, it was worth trying.  I appreciate your advice! Thank YOU!!!

Comment: @valerieclark in that case, I would just remove the twisttie and reglue it with a more suitable adhesive - many two part epoxies are fine at high temperatures.

Comment: I just found some heat resistant epoxy (up to 600 degrees) at lowe's for $8. :)

Comment: @valerieclark that'll do it.  If you can (without risking breaking it more), try to remove the superglue.  Acetone (most nail polish remover) disolves superglue.  If not, just leave it and add the epoxy.